# Caching an arraylist

Tags: android, caching, arraylist

I have a question. How do I create a Cache class to store arraylist data so that when the android device has no internet connection, the user would still be able to read data from the app. Such that I need to cache an arraylist to provide the app with an easy access to its data. Can someone help me with this? Appreciate any help given on this.

Comment: Just make the arraylist static. Then check if it is empty() if it isn't you have a cached arraylist!

Comment: @Blundell are you sure that works?

Comment: Yes one hundred percent.

Answer (score 0):

You have options:

1. Just create a class and make an arraylist there and hold your data there - this is the inmemory cache.
2. Create a class which will be store the data in shared preferences, or a file, or in db your data.
3. Combine two options.

Comment: yes, but i think it's preferable to use an xml file , and store it on the phone ,and then parse it to get informations when u don't have a connection internet

Comment: Could you give me an example of storing the arraylist in a class?

Comment: @Houcine Hey. Could you also give an example storing an arraylist into an xml file?